# Mapfish/Geoserver printing: layer problems

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

I am in the process of migrating my map application to another server with a newer Geoserver version (from 2.4 to the latest version available (master) using the 2.7-SNAPSHOT version of the printing extension (for testing reasons)). My print button in my application was working so far on the old server, but on the new server I keep getting this kind of error:

```
Error while generating PDF:
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/ (spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:786)
at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page$1.add(Page.java:76)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock.render(MapBlock.java:81)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:30)
at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:173)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:366)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:184)
at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doPost(MapPrinterServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:43)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/ (spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:136)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.<init>(HTTPMapReader.java:76)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.TileableMapReader.<init>(TileableMapReader.java:42)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.OsmMapReader.<init>(OsmMapReader.java:50)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.OsmMapReader$Factory.create(OsmMapReader.java:43)
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.MapReaderFactoryFinder.create(MapReaderFactoryFinder.java:36)
at org.mapfish.print.map.MapChunkDrawer.renderImpl(MapChunkDrawer.java:120)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.tableLayout(ChunkDrawer.java:49)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:786)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1765)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:549)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:764)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:889)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1774)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2602)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:727)
... 98 more
Caused by: org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/
at org.mapfish.print.map.readers.HTTPMapReader.checkSecurity(HTTPMapReader.java:133)
... 120 more
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction what to look for in order to get rid of this error?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it was kind of obvious (as the stack trace said (it seems I was kind of blind at that moment)): It is a security issue: As soon as you add the  url of the host of the respective layer to your config.yaml (in the "printing" directory in your Geoserver data directory (in the "hosts:" section)), the printing starts working again :)

Comment: please mark this as the answer to your own question you are allowed to do this. Please do not edit the title to 'Solved' thanks. Accepting the Answer will indicate to users that the question has a solution.

Comment: @Jan Peters-Anders Did you have to restart geoserver?